# While a cell is selected in a specific column do something when not error msg

Tags: vba, excel

Hello am trying to do a code like below

```
Do while (the selected cell is in the column b)
Code...

End Loop
Message error
```

When I click the button when the selected cell is not in the column b want to appear error msg

Comment: Could you please clarify your question and highlight the problematic part? Thanks and regards,

Comment: Basically I want to know the command that show which column is active when a cell of the column is selected

Comment: Didn't answered. Listen when I click the button when the selected cell is not in the column b want to appear error msg

Answer (score 0):

Provided that a single cell is selected, then you can achieve the desired result by using the following statement:

```
' get the column number
col = Selection.Column()
```

Column "B" corresponds to Column number 2. If selection is not in a column 2, then pop-up the Error Message (as per your requirement).

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you can try something like this:

```
Dim r As Range

'assign the selection to a variable
'but make sure it is a range
If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then Set r = Selection

'check if something is assigned to r; meaning a range is selected
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    'check if it is somewhere in Column B
    If Not Intersect(r, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        'do your stuff here
    Else
        'your error message here
        MsgBox "Invalid Selection", vbCritical
    End If
End If
```

Above code uses `MsgBox` to act as your error message.
Is this what you're trying? HTH.